# Applicable for the Arguments location Manager Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, arguments

I'm relatively new to both Java and the android platform and I have come across a problem in my code that is just completely beyond me. I am trying to lock onto a users location and move the camera to that location using the google maps api v2 however this is without success even with constant reading of resources and attempts.

> The method requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, LocationListener) in the type >LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, LocationListener) >MainActivity.java  /Loca/src/com/afrostudio/loca   line 91 Java Problem

Also a very recent error has randomly occured:

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

Any help would be fantastic please :)

```
package com.afrostudio.loca;

import android.app.ActionBar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        private GoogleMap map;  

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    public class googleMap extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Define a listener that responds to location updates
            LocationListener locationListner = new LocationListener() {

             @Override
             public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              double latti = location.getLatitude();
              double longi = location.getLongitude();

              CameraUpdate center=
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latti,
                                longi));
                    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

                    map.moveCamera(center);
                    map.animateCamera(zoom);

             }
            };
            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() 
        {
           super.onDestroyView(); 
           Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
           FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft.remove(fragment);
           ft.commit();
       }

    }

    public class MyFragment2 extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        }
    }

    public class MyFragment3 extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new googleMap();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        switch(position) {
            case 1:
                fragment = new googleMap();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MyFragment2();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new MyFragment3();
                break;
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#A4C639"));     
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably just need to clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

The R error thing has to do with your xml files (layouts) check them carefully. Try cleaning the project as well... As for the Location I sugest you to use the LocationClient, it is newer and performs better... https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html